# Analyzing logs offsite, with a different computer

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, logs, syslog

I have a computer deployed with no internet access. I have small windows in which to copy the log directory to a USB stick and analyze offsite.

If I pull the logs off of a CentOS / RHEL system -journalctl. How do I analyze/parse them using a different system?

I looked at reading them as text and this seemed to give me garbage.

I am using a mac but have access to a windows machine and also some Linux computers.

Answer (score 1):

You can access this from a linux computer that has journalctl installed using:

```
journalctl --file system@xxxxxxxx.journal
```

You can dump the database to text for reading on your mac or windows machine with:

```
journalctl --no-pager [file] > journalfile.txt
```